# Is it OK to use a macro for an operator, or a macro defined by `\DeclareMathOperator`, as a non-operator?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, typography

Macros like `\det`, I believe, is intended to be used before some expression, but sometimes I wish to use them as in `\det \in \mathbf{VP}`.  Is it acceptable to use them like this instead of using `\mathrm`?

Likewise, I sometimes define a macro `\perm` by `\DeclareMathOperator` and use it as in `\perm \in \mathbf{VNP}`.  Is this OK?

So far, I haven't noticed any differences between operator macros and `\mathrm` in these examples, but I'd like to ask this matter to TeXperts here.  I'd be grateful if you could give me information regarding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be differences: consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\det+\det\in\mathbf{VP}$

${\det}+{\det}\in\mathbf{VP}$
\end{document}
```

In the first case the spacing is wrong, because the `+` is interpreted as an ordinary symbol, because it doesn't make sense between two operators. In the second case the spacing is the same as if we said

```
$\mathrm{det}+\mathrm{det}\in\mathbf{VP}$
```

because adding braces around a subformula treats it as if it were a unique ordinary symbol. So, if you use an operator as an ordinary symbol in some cases, surround it with braces. If it's *always* used like that and not as an operator, a new definition is in order.

[image]

Comment: By "a new definition," do you mean the use of `\newcommand` and `\mathrm`?

Comment: @Pteromys That's it: `\DeclareMathOperator` is not a substitute for `\mathrm`